# Unity: Even when the "player" game object gets destroyed, the text doesn't appear

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been using Unity to create a simple 2D game but the problem is that even when the game object "player" gets destroyed, the gameobject "isDead" (text) doesn't appear.

This is my script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class youDied_Text : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform player;
    private Text isDead;
    // public static bool isDead;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    

    private void Start() {
        isDead = GetComponent<Text>();    
    }
    void checkForDeath()
    {
        if (player==false)
        {
            isDead.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            isDead.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
        checkForDeath();
    }
}
```

This script is attached in the text which I need to display in UI element.

Comment: Do your `Find` once, as needed, or directly set the reference from the inspector.  Calling `Find` every frame is not a good habit to be in.  On that same note, you risk throwing a null ref on your `Find` line since you cannot access the transform of a null object.  If the result of FindWithTag is null, you'll get a null ref error.

Comment: Is this script on the inactive gameobject?  Gameobjects that are inactive will not run scripts attached to them.

Comment: The script is on the text UI element. And that null ref is exactly what I want, so that I can set the text UI element as "active" in the gameplay.

Comment: I need a way to return false if a particular game object is destroyed and true if that game object is still active, all this every frame.

Comment: The type of player is Transform not a Boolean. So in your `checkForDeath` function code, it not equals in `player == false`

Comment: @leimenghao there is an implicit operator [`bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As was noted currently you would get a `NullReferenceException` which is definitely **not** what you want.
- There is absolutely no need / redundancy going through `Transform` at all actually. Simply store the `GameObject` reference instead
- You are currently setting the object to inactive which has the `Text` attached ... which is **the same** object your component is attached to as well!

  => As soon as you end up in the second case once you set it to inactive => from now on `Update` is never called anymore!

---

In general as it sounds like this should only happen once anyway I would use a more event driven approach and have a component on your player like e.g.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent onDied;

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        onDied.Invoke();
    }
}
```

And then simply attach a listener/callback to that event **once** without poll checking states. You can do this either via the Inspector directly (just like in e.g. Button.onClick) or via code like e.g.

```
public class youDied_Text : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Already reference things via the Inspector if possible!
    [SerializeField] private GameObject player;
    [SerializeField] private Text isDead;

    private void Awake() 
    {
        if(!isDead) isDead = GetComponent<Text>(); 

        isDead.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // If you want to rather set it via the Inspector remove all the rest here
        //if(!player) player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player"). GetComponent<Player>();
        // or even simpler
        if(!player) player = FindObjectOfType<Player>(); 
        player.onDied.AddListener(OnPlayerDied);  
    }

    // If you want to rather set it via the Inspector make this public
    private void OnPlayerDied()
    {
        isDead.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```